# Working with sensors in Android on different hardware

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to develop a reusable java class file that will do few common reusable task. It will work with different sensors. I wanted to know if the behavior of the function will remain same in case if a person using different phone.

What I mean is say I tested my function using Sony phone, other going to use Samsung, LG, Moto and any other Device manufacturer.

1. Now will the sensitivity of the sensor will change as the manufacturer of device changes?
2. If yes, then How can I put a calibration stage to make the function behavior somewhat same across all available device?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To 1)Yes. They use different sensors.  A model "A" accelerometer from FooCorp is not going to give the same results as a model "B" from BazCorp.  In fact, two identical model "A"s will give different results.  2)Too broad.  It depends on what type of sensor and what you're using it for.

Comment: To be specific I wanted to implement just for accelerometer sensor for few most used device only (say Samsung, Sony, Moto, LG, Micromax ). Use is yet not defined, but I want to get the values that is near by to each other. Say if I want to detect left right shake, then I will compare those values with a user acceptable value. But as it is  not same for different phone, I got the issue.

Comment: So I thought to make a very simple check state, Say put the phone on table and compare the value with the your device value. Using this way I thought I will add +- constant value based on the deviation I got from my device value. But I found All device giving same value, but when we shake, sensitivity is different.

Answer (score 0):

1)As I said was yes.

2)On an accelerometer you'll have 2 major sources of issues.  One is how much noise is in the signal.  The other is what is the rest value-  how much acceleration does a device at rest measure.  It should read about 9.8 in vector force (gravity), but mine reads about 10.2 at rest.  Other devices differ.

Whether that matters depends on if you have a big signal problem or a small signal problem.  Big signal problems-  lets say if you expect the phone to read events where it jumps by 1 or 2 m/s^2- are generally immune to both of these issues, because the size of the event >> the size of the problem.

For small signals, you need to worry about both.  The resting signal is fairly easy-  you take a running average of the last 20 or so values, and look for changes based on that value rather than the expected 9.8.  (Note:  the number 20 is pulled from my ass, it may need more or less to converge).

Noise is harder-  the smaller your signal is, the more difficult it is to tell noise from signal.  There are various techniques to deal with this, most of them cost you time (you need more data to analyze).  But here's the problem-  I'm not qualified to really get into a lot of them (there's a reason I write software rather than design circuits), and if you had to ask this question you're nowhere near qualified to work on it.

Comment: Thanks, Now I got some direction to think.

Comment: One other heads up-  if you do end up needing someone because you have a small signal problem, seek out people with experience in digital signal processing and/or electrical engineering.